# Firebase unauthorized domain despite adding to to authorized domains

Tags: firebase, authentication

I'm attempting to use Firebase Auth to use google sign-in. I've enabled Google Sign-In as a method, and added my domain to the list of whitelisted domains, like this:

[image: Domain list]

My javascript code is very simple, just like this:

```
const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    var user = result.user;
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

But when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
This domain (<my domain>.38) is not authorized to run this operation. Add it to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab.
```

What am I doing wrong?